# How to get the like list of open graph object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Recently I have created several facebook like button, each of them use iframe and href to link with an open graph object url. Then url will redirect the user into the facebook apps.

But, how can I get the like list from these open graph object? I have pass the urls into fql debugger and want to get the like list, it return nothing. Then I use graph API to check my open graph object page, it return the normal data without the like array list.

So now I cannot get the user id and their name, and I still don't know why I cannot get this... I saw some webpage in the facebook sample that can get the like list. This really make me down.

Answer (score 0):

Due to privacy policies, there is no real way to extract this information.

You  might get the friends list who liked the link, try this

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id IN (SELECT link_id from link WHERE url = 'YOUR URL HERE') and user_id IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )
```

Comment: This cannot be done because the link table does not allow using url as search key. However, I change it to object_url table, search and found the id, and put it as the like table's object_id to search. This still not work --- The result return null array. 

If I can not take the result, I want to know what makes my open graph object page wrong. Because I see some webpage including the open graph object that can access its like list by using graph API. So I guess that should be something wrong or mistake in my open graph page, or something I have not setup......

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get the fan count of your page.

select fan_count from page where page_id = 'page_id'

You can't list down all the users of your page. Instead you can check if a particular user is your page's fan or not using this query.

select uid from page_fan where uid = 'user_id' and page_id = 'page_id'